# Microsoft Dynamics GP 2013 Development Environment

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

Can I create development environment for Dynamics GP 2013 with web client installed in a single machine?

Comment: It's stupid to just vote down question, by just saying this question doesn't show any research, You can not reply in YES or NO but can down vote. What is obvious for you maybe obscure for others.huh.

Comment: I hope you'll get better feedback now that I changed the tags to fit your technology.

Comment: Thanks Filburt, I guess yes it will help. :)